# Creating a DVD menu for a library system

Tags: c++, eclipse, oop, menu

I am in the process of creating a library system. I am creating a Dvd menu now and this how it looks right now:

```
switch (dvdOption){

           case '1':
              cout << "Enter Name of DVD: ";
              cin.getline( name, 80);
              DVD *item;
              item = lib.searchDVD( name );
              if( item != NULL){
                cout << "DVD already exist, do you want to update the existing DVD?" << endl; 
                cout << "1 for Yes" << endl;
                cout << "2 for No"  << endl;
                cin >> response;
                if (response == '1'){

                }
              }
              cout << "Enter Director of DVD: ";
              cin.getline(director, 80);
              cout << "Enter no of copies: ";
              cin.getline(copies, 80);
              lib.insertDVD( name, director, atoi(copies));
              break;
           case '2':
              cout << "Enter Name of DVD:\n";
              cin.getline(name, 80);
              lib.deleteDVD(name);
              break;
           case '3':
              cout << "Enter Name of DVD:\n";
              cin.getline(name, 80);
              DVD *item;
              item = lib.searchDVD( name );
              if( item != NULL){
                cout << "DVD found\n" << item->name << endl << item->director << endl << item->copies << endl;
              }
              else
              cout << "DVD not found\n";
              break;
           case '4':
              break;
           case '5':
              exit(0);
              break;
           case '6':
              cout << "Invalid selection!" << endl;
              system("pause");
              break;
        }
        }
```

Currently when I add a new dvd to the database and then add another dvd with the same name and author it doesn't get updated, so when I search for it I get the first dvd that was added. So what I would like to do is when I select the option of adding a new DVD it will ask for a name and then the system should search the library and see if it already exists if it does it should give another option asking whether you want update the existing DVD. I have done the searching part but need help updating the system with new details entered.

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify.  You have a function that inserts into the library.  You have a function that searches for a DVD.  What do you mean by update and how is it different from searching and inserting?

Comment: So basically when I add a new dvd for example say I add the dvd "home alone" and 5 copies are added, and then say I add more copies of the same dvd say I add another 3 dvds of the same film, so when I search for "home alone" it shows 5 copies instead of showing 8 copies.

Comment: what is your primary key in database> is it set to unique?

Comment: Sorry Im not quite sure what you are asking? Im quite new to c++/oop